# Как реализовать таймер в Android с помощью AlarmManager?

Tags: android, таймер, android-alarm-manager

Народ, выручите пожалуйста, я никак не могу найти объяснение работы подобного таймера или примеров такой реализации которая бы удоволетворяла условию задачи:

Условие задачи:
Нужно чтобы AlarmManager при срабатывании запускал одну строчку кода ровно через 2 минуты, без задержек.

Строчка кода:

```
TcpClient.RECONNECT = true;
```

Но при этом нужна возможность его перезапускать, т.е отменять запуск таймера и снова заводить.

Comment: Alarm Manager имеет ограничение на частоту запуска (~8 минут) и это указано в документации, Для ваших целей используйте ForegroundService с постоянным уведомлением.

Comment: У меня это и так реализовано. Только вот к чему вы это написали?

Answer (score 0):

AlarmManager не подходит для этой задачи. В AlarmManager минимальное время срабатывания таймера 8 минут.

Видимо я плохо ориентируюсь в англоязычной документации, ведь оказывается существует вот эта страница документации:
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#best-practices

В ней есть примеры кода, ограничения и всё что необходимо для полноценной реализации таймера с помощью AlarmManager для разных задач.

Я также нашел видео на youtube в котором на русском языке рассказывают про реализацию таймера с помощью AlarmManager и там я эту страницу документации и нашел:
https://youtu.be/nfzTYe-J6Uk